# Javascript: Is This Truly Signed Integer Division

Tags: javascript, integer, ecmascript-6, integer-division

Given the following code, where both `a` and `b` are `Number`s representing values within the range of signed 32-bit signed integers:

```
var quotient = ((a|0) / (b|0))|0;
```

and assuming that the runtime is in full compliance with the ECMAScript 6 specifications, will the value of `quotient` **always** be the correct signed integer division of `a` and `b` as integers? In other words, is this a proper method to achieve true signed integer division in JavaScript that is equivalent to the machine instruction?

Comment: Have you tried looking for any counterexamples that might prove it *isn't* always correct?

Comment: I have not. Since JavaScript formally deals in all floating point, I would see the question coming down to, is the result of the double precision division of two mathematical integers in the range of a 32-bit signed integer, followed by a truncation to a 32-bit signed integer and a simulation of overflow according to the `ToInt32()` abstract operation specified by EMCAScript 6, equivalent to an integer division of the same mathematical values? I don't feel I understand the process of floating point division well enough to answer this myself or derive counterexamples, which is why I asked here.

Comment: For division by zero, no — it returns 0 instead of throwing an exception: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179876/how-does-asm-js-handle-divide-by-zero

Comment: [`Math.prototype.trunc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) might be useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm no expert on floating-point numbers, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) says that  doubles have 52 bits of precision. Logically, it seems that 52 bits should be enough to reliably approximate integer division of 32-bit integers.

Dividing the minimum and maximum 32-bit signed ints, `-2147483648 / 2147483647`, produces `-1.0000000004656613`, which is still a reasonable amount of significant digits. The same goes for its inverse, `2147483647 / -2147483648`, which produces `-0.9999999995343387`.

An exception is [division by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179876/how-does-asm-js-handle-divide-by-zero), which I mentioned in a comment. As the linked SO question states, integer division by zero normally throws some sort of error, whereas floating-point coercion results in `(1 / 0) | 0 == 0`.

**Update:** According to [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c), integer division in C truncates towards zero, which is what `|0` does in JavaScript. In addition, division by 0 is undefined, so JavaScript is technically not incorrect in returning zero. Unless I've missed anything else, the answer to the original question should be yes.

**Update 2:** Relevant sections of the ECMAScript 6 spec: how to [divide numbers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-applying-the-div-operator) and how to [convert to a 32-bit signed integer](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toint32), which is [what `|0` does](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-binary-bitwise-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation).